# Saving a drawing in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a paint application in windows Forms (C#). It has different tabs and there is a pictureBox in one tab which acts as my drawing surface. I am saving the image by copying from screen using the following code :

```
Bitmap bmpz = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
Graphics gSaveAs = Graphics.FromImage(bmpz);
Rectangle rectSaveAs = pictureBox1.RectangleToScreen(pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
gSaveAs.CopyFromScreen(rectSaveAs.Location, Point.Empty, pictureBox1.Size);
```

Is there a better way to save the drawing? The above method produces an image but need not be same as the one drawn. For eg, if I have a pop up or something on top of the picturebox, then the saved image will also have a pop up in it. How can I save just what is drawn on the screen?

Comment: you should use pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap to save BackgroundImage, Image and any Drawing from the Paint event into a file!

Comment: Thanks @TaW. It worked.

Answer (score -1):

I would draw on a Bitmap and present it in the PictureBox. This way you doesn't need to grab the screen.

```
Bitmap backPage = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
pictureBox1.Image = backPage;
```

---

```
using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(backPage))
{
    // draw
}

pictureBox1.Refresh();
```